# Can't Increment php variable in javascript loop for draw polygons on google map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have some problem, what i want is draw polygons on google map with given coordinate from Database, just for test i draw 2 polygon only which is have a different number of coordinate. Here's my code

```
<script>
var map;

function initialize()
{
   var va = new Array();
   for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
   {
  va[i] = new Array();
   }
var x=new google.maps.LatLng(-7.175993,112.650729);

var count=new Array();
var allcoor=new Array();
var mySplitResult;
//----------Problem May Be Start Right There----------------------------------
<?php
  $indeksline=0;
?>
for(var a=0;a<2;a++)
{
 //To get number of coordinate
 count[a] = "<?php include_once("koneksi.php");
 $sql3="SELECT a.Informasi from asset a LIMIT $indeksline , 1";
 $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
 $data3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3);
 $pieces = explode("|", $data3[0]);
 $numberOfWords = count(explode("|", $data3[0]));
 echo $numberOfWords;?>";

 //To get Coordinate
 allcoor[a] = "<?php include_once("koneksi.php"); 
 $sql3="SELECT a.Informasi from asset a LIMIT indeksline , 1";
 $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
 $data3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3);
 echo $data3[0];?>";    

 //Split Coordinate with delimiter |
 mySplitResult = allcoor[a].split("|");
 for (var j=0;j<count[a];j++)
 {
    va[a][j]=new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(mySplitResult[j].split(",")[0]),parseFloat(mySplitResult[j].split(",")[1]));
 }

 //Increment $indeksline that use for next polygon
 <?php
   $indeksline = $indeksline+1;
 ?>
}
var mapProp = {
  center:x,
  zoom:19,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
 };

map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
{
 var flightPath=new google.maps.Polygon({
 path:va[i],
 strokeColor:"##FF0000",
 strokeOpacity:0.8,
 strokeWeight:3,
 fillColor:"##FF0000",
 fillOpacity:0.35
 });
flightPath.setMap(map);
```

The Problem is on the loop, that doesnt increment variable php indeksline and always draw first polygon. Anyone Help

Answer (score 1):

php is executed first on the server side

javascript is executed afterwards on the browser, so you cannot increment the PHP variable. only use it.

You should not mix PHP code and Javascript like this. Take out all PHP code, read from database, get results etc. Then just pass to Javascript what you need and handle it as a JS variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should be  spliting you code like this way . Php should provide all data to client(browser) before you do anything meaning full in javascript

## php

```
<?php
 include_once("koneksi.php");
 $offset=0;
 $limit=2; // you want to show two 
 $sql3="SELECT a.Informasi from asset a LIMIT $offset, $limit";
 $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
 $data=[];
 while( $dataRow= mysql_fetch_row($result3)){
    $data[]=explode("|", $dataRow);
  }
 ?>
```

## javascript

```
    <script>
     // set javascript variable in php
     var poly_data=<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
     var va=new Array();

    for(a=0; a< poly_data.length ; a++){
     //no of coordinates
     var mySplitResult=poly_data[a];
     va[a]=new Array();

     //put the reset of code here  
     for (var j=0;j< mySplitResult.length;  j++)
     {

      va[a][j]=new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(mySplitResult[j].split(",")[0]),
            parseFloat(mySplitResult[j].split(",")[1])
            );
     }

 }

  //your reset of code

 </script>
```